# numpy: content to index , index to content

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

My question is about Numpy array's content to index, index to content.
Is there any efficient and elegant way?

from this (one dimension, million value):

```
a = np.array ([0,1,1,1,3,3,5,1,2,3,6,9,10,....])
```

---

to list or ndarray  :

```
output = [[0],[1,2,3,7],[8],[4,5,9],[],[6],[10],[],[],[11],[12],....]

output[0] = value 0 , result:[0]       = locatoin 0 in a 
output[1] = value 1 , result:[1,2,3,7] = location 1 ,2 ,3 , 7 in a
output[2] = value 2 , result:[8] = location 8 
output[3] = value 3 , result:[4,5,9] = location 4,5,9 
output[4] = value 4 , result:[] = location nothing
........
```

Comment: What's the exact logic behind your output and what you have tried already? Also, please explain what's the problem with your code as well.

Comment: Ok @Kasramvd, enhanced the result for the logic expansion.I tried a standard for loop in python, extremely slow in array size about a million.

Comment: In general, going from an index to the content is going to be very fast and constant time. Finding the index of an element in an array will be slow, and scale linearly with the size of an array. That being said, the fastest way will be to use `numpy.where`

Comment: I don't know `numpy`, but it looks to me like you have the wrong data structure for your application, if you need to do this operation frequently.  For example, in addition to the array, have a dictionary that for each item in the array holds a list of indices in the array that contain the item.  Of course, that means you'd need to update the dictionary on all stores to the array.  `numpy` may have a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scipy.sparse` like so:

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>>
>>> def enum_loc_per_val(a):
...     x = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(a.shape, dtype=np.int8), a, np.arange(a.size+1))).tocsc()
...     return np.split(x.indices, x.indptr[1:-1])
... 
>>> 
>>> enum_loc_per_val(a)
[array([0], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 3, 7], dtype=int32), array([8], dtype=int32), array([4, 5, 9], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32), array([6], dtype=int32), array([10], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32), array([11], dtype=int32), array([12], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: It works like a charm. But still prefer numpy way, not scipy.Its all about the application weight.Still , its fast and elegant.Million Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a solution without a loop completely but a solution that will work involves using the `where` function. I've tested it on a list of random ints and it's pretty fast.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,1,1,3,3,5,1,2,3,6,9,10]) 

output = [np.where(a == x)[0] if x in a else [] for x in range(a.min(), a.max())]
```

And here you get `output=`

```
[array([0]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 7]),
 array([8]),
 array([4, 5, 9]),
 [],
 array([6]),
 array([10]),
 [],
 [],
 array([11])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with 1D arrays<sup>*</sup>  you can use *broadcasting* to compare your array with its unique items to find the desire positions.

```
In [68]: a = np.array ([0,1,1,1,3,3,5,1,2,3,6,9,10, 10, 9, 9]) 

In [69]: arr = np.unique(a)

In [70]: x, y= np.where(arr[:,None] == a)

In [71]: inds = np.where(x[:-1] - x[1:] != 0)[0] + 1

In [72]: np.split(y, inds)
Out[72]: 
[array([0]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 7]),
 array([8]),
 array([4, 5, 9]),
 array([6]),
 array([10]),
 array([11, 14, 15]),
 array([12, 13])]
```

If it's really necessary to find the missed items although it's not clear what's the logic behind your expected output but it seems that you're finding the indices for all the items between `a.min()` and `a.max()`. In that case you can use `np.arange(a.min(), a.max())` as `arr` and then put `arr[:,None] == a` in a mask then you can find the indices of missed items as following:

```
In [115]: missed = np.where((~mask).all(1))[0]

In [116]: missed
Out[116]: array([4, 7, 8])
```

---

<sub>* From [documentation](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc):  For 3-dimensional arrays this is certainly efficient in terms of lines of code, and, for small data sets, it can also be computationally efficient. For large data sets, however, the creation of the large 3-d array may result in sluggish performance.
Also, Broadcasting is a powerful tool for writing short and usually intuitive code that does its computations very efficiently in C. However, there are cases when broadcasting uses unnecessarily large amounts of memory for a particular algorithm. In these cases, it is better to write the algorithm's outer loop in Python. This may also produce more readable code, as algorithms that use broadcasting tend to become more difficult to interpret as the number of dimensions in the broadcast increases.</sub>

Comment: Using `unique` doesn't handle the case where there is a number missing from the original array. You'd have to use an approach similar to my answer to handle that.

Comment: @ncfirth In that case instead of `unique` we can use a `range` but it's still easy to find the position of missing items if it's needed.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but using `range` doesn't help. It'll have to be a post processing step to add in the missing items.

Comment: @Kasramvd, thanks for the answer.But somehow I cant use it on my data, My nparray.shapes is (481020L,) and max value=80269.It warn:x , y = np.where(arr[:,None] == idxAll)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward Python solution is to collect the values in a dictionary:

```
In [181]: dd = {i:[] for i in range(0,11)}
In [182]: a = np.array([0,1,1,1,3,3,5,1,2,3,6,9,10]) 
In [183]: for i,v in enumerate(a.tolist()):
     ...:     dd[v].append(i)
     ...:     
In [184]: dd
Out[184]: 
{0: [0],
 1: [1, 2, 3, 7],
 2: [8],
 3: [4, 5, 9],
 4: [],
 5: [6],
 6: [10],
 7: [],
 8: [],
 9: [11],
 10: [12]}
```

If you don't care about the `[]` cases, you could use a `collections.defaultdictionary`.

I suggest the `tolist()` because iteration on a list is faster than iteration on an array.  But whether that step helps in overall time, I don't know.  This kind of problem needs timing tests.

I'm sure there are previous questions like this; I vaguely remember answering one in the past half year.  But searching will take longer than writing this answer.